# Please share 'SharePoint Color Palette Tool'

Tags: sharepoint-online, theme

Does anyone have **SharePoint Color Palette Tool** distr?
I have one but it show .Net error; Link provided by Microsoft is broken (https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=38182). The [new generator](https://fluentuipr.z22.web.core.windows.net/heads/master/theming-designer/index.html) is working but imho it can nothing..

Want to set background image to modern sites. As I understand from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites) - we still able to apply .spcolor themes in modern too..

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue - I used the software before, but it has now been removed from the Microsoft site (no idea why...)

However, I found it! It is here: https://sharepoint-color-palette-tool.software.informer.com/1.0/

Happy for you to reach out if you have any concerns, but it does work :)

Comment: hehe) Thank You much for sharing! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could go to **[this link](https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000270047-sharepoint-color-palette-and-themes-tool)** to get **SharePoint Color Palette and Themes Tool**.

======================= **Updated Answer** ======================

Yes, you are right. **The SharePoint Color Palette and Themes Tool** is third-party tool from Shortpoint. You could use **[the Theme Generator Tool](https://fabricweb.z5.web.core.windows.net/pr-deploy-site/refs/heads/master/theming-designer/index.html)** to create a custom theme in SharePoint Online.

For more information, please refer to **[this post](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-configure-and-apply-a-custom-theme-in-sharepoint-online/)**.

Comment: I saw this but as I understand this is third-party tool from Shortpoint?

Comment: Hi, Gennady G. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank You EchoDu_MSFT. I'm searching for an old working distributive that can generate *.spcolor files. This new generator I know, it is pointed in my post, but thank You twice.

Comment: Hi, Gennady G. Thanks for your reply. It's my honor to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this GitHub Pages repository, it is a nice handout of ShP 2016 CSS classes and you can also see what each of them do:

> https://zerg00s.github.io/sp-modern-classes/